# There is no continuous map from $D^2\to S^1$ such that...

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification, fundamental-groups

**Proposition:** There is no continuous map from the unit disc $D^2$ to its boundary $S^1$ whose restriction to $S^1$ is the identity on $S^1$.

**My proof:** Assume that there is such an $f$. Let $g: S^1\to S^1$ be a continuous map. Then, $g\circ f: D^2 \to S^1$ is an extension of $g$ to $D^2$. Hence $\pi_1(S^1)=0$. Contradiction.

The simplicity of my solution makes me suspicious. Is everything correct?

Comment: Yes, everything's correct. You could also say that $(t,x) \mapsto f(t\cdot x)$ would show that $S^1$ is contractible; $x \mapsto -f(x)$ would be a continuous self-map without fixed point; probably a lot more contradictions to be easily had.

Comment: The simplicity of your solution should make you proud of yourself.

Comment: I think the thing to say here is the fact that $\pi_1(S^1) \neq 0$ is not trivial to prove, so your proof is only "simple" up to a difficult theorem.

Comment: Is there such a map such that its restriction to the boundary $S^1$ is homotopic to the identity map?

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is no retraction $r: D^2 \rightarrow S^1$. For if there was, the induced homomorphism of fundamental groups of the inclusion map $j: S^1 \rightarrow D^2$ would be injective. But since the fundamental group of $D^2$ is trivial, while the fundamental group of $S^1$ is not, this contradicts the induced homomorphism of the inclusion map being injective. Therefore, no such retraction $r$ exists.